# how to set increase the rate of sound and repeat this sound in Touch down event in iphone sdk

Tags: media-player, avaudioplayer, ios5

I am using the 9 button each button has a tag.
when I single touch mp3 file play on Touch Up Inside method.
and when I touch held increase the sound rate of mp3 file.
The main issue - it is also playing the sound when I release the button.
and I want to this-
-When I keep it pressed, the sound file should repeat itself until I
release the button on the Touch Down method.
Can any one Solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer setRate can help you change rates

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have done increase the rate option .
but  when I call the   Tuch UP Inside method   it is also playing the sound when I release the button.